# Error when trying to disable default monitoring via Ruby

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can use the REST API to disable the default monitoring for a Virtual Guest but I cannot seem to get this working in Ruby.

Curl Example:

```
curl -s --user "$SOFTLAYER_USERNAME:$SOFTLAYER_API_KEY" -X POST --data @editmonitoring.json "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/26223285/editObject"
```

The editmonitoring.json file is

```
{ "parameters": [
    {
      "monitoringServiceFlag": "false"
    }
]
}
```

My Ruby file is

```
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:timeout => 120)

parameters = [
  {
        'id' => 26223283,
        'monitoringServiceFlag' => 'false'
    }
]

begin
  editMonitoring = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].editObject(parameters)
  puts editMonitoring
rescue Exception => exception
   puts "There is an error in the order: #{exception}"
end
```

The error I get back is

```
$ ruby disablemonitoring.rb
There is an error in the order: Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::editObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to set this flag to **monitoringServiceFlag = false**, it **indicates that the server has an advanced monitoring package installed**, the only way to set this flag as false, is cancelling the service.

If your goal is to cancel this service, try the following ruby script:

```
# Cancel Advanced Monitoring Package for a VSI
#
# Important manual pages
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject
#
# License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc.<sldn@softlayer.com>

require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

# Create connection1
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:timeout => 120)

# Define your vsi's identifier
vsi_id = 15002321

# Define an object mask to get additional information from monitoring
object_mask = 'mask[billingItem[monitoringBillingItems]]'

begin
  # Getting vsi information
  vsi_result = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].object_mask(object_mask).object_with_id(vsi_id).getObject

  # Define template to cancel monitoring billing item
  template = {
    "accountId" => 112233,
    "items"=>[{
      "billingItemId"=> vsi_result['billingItem']['monitoringBillingItems'][0]['id'],
        "immediateCancellationFlag"=> true
    }]
  }

  # Canceling service
  result = client['SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request'].createObject(template)
  puts result
rescue Exception => exception
   puts "Error: #{exception}"
end
```

Comment: So it looks like I found a way to do this but seeking advice on if this will cause any other issues. If I use `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getNetworkMonitors` I can get the monitoring ID. I then pass that to `SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host::deleteObject` and the default monitoring is removed from the server. Confirmed this via the portal and API.